# How can I make Chromium start full-screen under X?

Tags: xorg, raspbian, chrome

I've installed Raspbian Jessie Lite and added on the minimum I can to get a browser running fullscreen. I started off with IceWeasel:

```
sudo apt-get install -y x-window-system iceweasel
```

And put this into my `.xinitrc`:

```
iceweasel "http://localhost/"
```

Now, when I run `startx` it loads IceWeasel. However, it only took up a small portion of the screen. I was able to fix that by loading IceWeasel, closing it, and then modifying the file that stored the window size and make it 1920x1080.

That was all fine, until I discovered IceWeasel didn't support all the nice new ECMAScript goodness Chrome did. So, I'm trying to swap for Chromium. I've managed to get it all installed, and I've changed my `.xinitrc` to this:

```
chromium-browser --start-maximized --kiosk http://localhost/
```

However, when this launches it only uses about (possibly exactly) half of the screen! I've tried various options but can't get it working. `--start-fullscreen` is even weirder and renders correctly but gets chopped in half! :(

Note: I'm trying to avoid installing any window manager/etc, as it seems like it shouldn't be required when IceWeasel is already all working correctly!?

IceWeasel:

[image: Iceweasel fullscreen]

Chromium (`--start-maximized` and `--kiosk`):

[image: Chromium not-quite fullscreen!]

Chromium (`--start-fullscreen`):

[image: Chromium chopped in half]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, with help from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1687545&p=11059377#post11059377) I got it working. Although that poster said it didn't work, I edited `.config/chromium/Default/Preferences` and explicitly set the window size:

### Before

```
"window_placement":
{
    "bottom":1060,
    "docked":false,
    "left":10,
    "maximized":true,
    "right":950,
    "top":10
    // ...
```

### After

```
"window_placement":
{
    "bottom":1080,
    "docked":false,
    "left":0,
    "maximized":true,
    "right":1920,
    "top":0
    // ...
```

I wondered if maybe this had been set badly by the first load of the app not being fullscreen, but I tried deleting `~/.config` and then loading it again, but it just recreated it with the left half of the screen. I guess I'll have to script loading Chromium, killing it, then rewriting that part of the file in my setup script! ;(

Comment: Mate you are a genius! This drove me nuts for days and I had almost given up -- I thought it was an xserver issue but apparently, Chromium has an issue when started in Kiosk right away -- thanks so much!

Comment: If your Preferences file is missing `window_placement`, it can be added under the `browser` key.

Reference: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/848e9ffcee90e576946f6217fcf570b0a1924380/chrome/test/data/profiles/window_placement/Default/Preferences

Answer (score 10):

even simpler that tweaking `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`, just use `--window-position=0,0` flag during chromium startup.

see [Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for full list of available chromium switches

Comment: This solved it for me. Here is the full combinations of switches I'm using for a raspberry pi kiosk for anyone who finds themselves in my position:

```chromium-browser \
  --window-size=1920,1080 \
  --kiosk \
  --incognito \
  --disable-infobars \
  --noerrdialogs \
  --disable-crash-report \
  --start-fullscreen \
  --start-maximized \
  --window-position=0,0 \
  --ignore-certificate-errors \
  --test-type \
  $(cat /boot/websites)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your monitor is smaller then 7000px

```
chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen
```

This command will detect your screen height / width

Now you also can use it in a bash script:

**/home/pi/full.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash/ 
chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen
```

and then run

```
startx /home/pi/full.sh
```

It will launch a fullscreen browser, from a non-gui terminal :D.

**NOT NEEDED,**

but for fun
I tested a bash code to get the screen resolution, but you don't need it..

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="$(fbset -s | awk '$1 == "geometry" { print $2" "$3 }')"
echo "$CMD"
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: `--window-size=7000,7000` sort of worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start Chromium in fullscreen then try adding this to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

```
@chromium-browser -e Fullscreen -a http://google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same symptoms, 10px offset top and left and only half the screen filled. I had trouble with the `window_placement` property not being there. Hardcoding the resolution wasn't an option for me since I want to support a wide range of monitors so I wrote this script that adds the window_placement property to the preferences file before starting the Chrome kiosk. It uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to manipulate the JSON file and [xdpyinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdpyinfo) to grab the resolution, so before you can use it run:

```
sudo apt install jq
```

kiosk.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

CHROMIUM_FILE=~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
RESOLUTION=$(xdpyinfo | grep -Po "(?<=dimensions:)\s*([0-9]{1,}x[0-9]{1,})" | sed "s: ::g")
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(echo $RESOLUTION | cut -d'x' -f1)
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(echo $RESOLUTION | cut -d'x' -f2)
printf -v WINDOW_PLACEMENT '.browser.window_placement |= {bottom: %s, right: %s, top: 0, left: 0, maximized: true}' $SCREEN_WIDTH $$

jq "$WINDOW_PLACEMENT" $CHROMIUM_FILE > tmp.json && mv tmp.json $CHROMIUM_FILE

chromium-browser --window-size=$SCREEN_WIDTH,$SCREEN_HEIGHT --start-maximized --no-default-browser-check --kiosk https://google.com
```

Interestingly, just writing the resolution into the JSON file wasn't enough. It fixed the 10px offset and made the window a little bit bigger but didn't fill the screen. Using the `--window-size` flag fixed that for me.

Answer (score 1):

After trying several of the answers given, the most robust solution seems to be to detect screen resolution and then set `--window-size=$WIDTH,$HEIGHT`, and add `--window-position=0,0` to position the window in the left top corner.

Here is a sample `.xinitrc` with useful options for starting is `--kiosk` mode:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

GEO="$(fbset -s | awk '$1 == "geometry" { print $2":"$3 }')"
WIDTH=$(echo "$GEO" | cut -d: -f1)
HEIGHT=$(echo "$GEO" | cut -d: -f2)

echo "Resolution: $WIDTH x $HEIGHT"

xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

unclutter &

chromium-browser --window-position=0,0 --window-size=$WIDTH,$HEIGHT  --app="https://google.com/" --start-maximized --no-default-browser-check --start-fullscreen --kiosk --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --fast --fast-start --disable-features=TranslateUI --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null  --password-store=basic
```

A full list of startup flags can be found here: https://codefodder.github.io/chrome-chromium-startup-flags/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> `--start-fullscreen`  Specifies if the browser should start in fullscreen mode, like if the user had pressed F11 right after startup.

as [listed](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#start-fullscreen) by Peter Beverloo's automatic web page of options.

Comment: Well, that one's even weirder... the window now takes up the full screen, yet the right half is black! I've edited a screenshot into my original question :(

Comment: That is weird! Does the cursor manage to travel over the black half?

Comment: Yeah, the cursor can go around the whole screen; just only the left half of Chromium is rendered. It's very weird; the rendered part is the same portion that --start-maximized set the window too. It's like some things are reading the screen size as half of what it actually is, and some is getting it correct (but why there would be two different ways for Chrome to figure out the screen size, I dunno!)

Comment: Got it sorted; see my answer. I can't explain why it happens (it also added a 10px border!), but I have a solution to it at least. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work for me